# Can't connect to kernel, HTTP 400 codes

Tags: apache, ssl, ipython

I'm trying to setup an IPython notebook server on my own server. The installation worked fine (I compiled and installed from the github source, 3.0.0).

I managed to setup basic HTTP connection, and notebooks worked.

However, since then, I did 2 things:
- I switched to ssl (generated the self-signed certificate) and https (enforced with an apache redirection from http)
- I added a redirection with proxy in apache to have subdomain.domain.com point to domain.com:8888

I can connect to the server fine, list the notebooks, and open one. But the notebooks can't connect to the kernels, the status is "Reconnecting" and I can't run any cell.

Here's the relevant apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    Redirect / https://sub.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-ipython.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-ipython.key
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    #ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ipython-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ipython-access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # setup the proxy
    #<Proxy *>
    #    Order allow,deny
    #    Allow from all
    #</Proxy>
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8888/
        #retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8888/
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's a sample session from ipython:

```
...
[I 17:02:51.383 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 17:02:51.383 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[I 17:02:51.383 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 17:03:04.701 NotebookApp] Kernel started: bb4905f6-d883-4efc-9282-869f098d2b22
[W 17:03:04.948 tornado.access] 400 GET /api/kernels/bb4905f6-d883-4efc-9282-869f098d2b22/shell (::1) 0.31ms referer=None
[W 17:03:10.110 tornado.access] 400 GET /api/kernels/bb4905f6-d883-4efc-9282-869f098d2b22/shell (::1) 0.27ms referer=None
[W 17:03:15.278 tornado.access] 400 GET /api/kernels/bb4905f6-d883-4efc-9282-869f098d2b22/shell (::1) 0.82ms referer=None
[W 17:03:20.505 tornado.access] 400 GET /api/kernels/bb4905f6-d883-4efc-9282-869f098d2b22/shell (::1) 0.51ms referer=None
```

And with --debug, every second a line like this pops:

```
[D 17:02:22.545 NotebookApp] Polling kernel...
```

EDIT: After fiddling around, I managed to make it work, but without the subdomain prefix, if I explicitly specify the port (with another config). So it seems the problem comes from the proxy.

Thanks for anyone taking time to read this!

Comment: I seem to having the same problem.  Are you saying that it works if you just don't use a subdomain/host?  Was there anything else?  What do you mean by "explicitly specify the port"?   I'm using:  ProxyPassMatch  (.*) http://localhost:8880 nocanon